# Mat-icon change for single row when button clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am implementing `mat-table`.

Where I want to change the `mat-icon` of a button based on `click event` only for single row in the table. I am able to change the icon but not able to do it for only single row.

Any suggestions on how I can fix that?

My stackblitz example: [Button-icon change](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugxyhc?file=src/main.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a property that handle value for the individual row. I have added property on array object and setting that expand and collapse.

Here is the working code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugxyhc-cbbtmz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-column-styling-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle of this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugxyhc-ri2neq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-column-styling-example.ts

All you have to do is to expand the object called PeriodicElement to also contain whether he is expanded or not. Once you do that you can ask if a certain element in a certain row is expanded and render accordingly.

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  isExpanded?: boolean; // Keep track of expanded state
}
expand(element: PeriodicElement, expanded: boolean) {
   element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <button (click)="expand(element, isExpanded)">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!element.isExpanded">expand_more</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="element.isExpanded">chevron_right</mat-icon>
  </button>
</td>
```